# Unit-test with time-dependant data without PowerMock

Tags: java, testing, mockito

My class has a method, that tries to perform some operations and return nano time after all operations are completed. When testing this method I get a problem, that **test result is always different** (because depends on current time).

How to test return value correctly? Is there way without PowerMock?

Example class:

```
class ExampleClass {
    public long performOperationsAndGetTimeNano(){
        //some operations...
        return Instant.now().getNano();
    }
    ...
}
```

Example test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExampleTest{
    private static final long EXPECTED_TIME = 555927900L;
    private ExampleClass subject;

    //init...

    @Test
    void performOperationAndGetTimeNano(){
        long actualTime = subject.performOperationAndGetTimeNano(); //always different result

        assertEquals(EXPECTED_TIME, actualTime); //always fails
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Michael
1) Such solution makes me change the real implementation for the test. It's a bad practice
2) We reveal implementation details, if we provide such Supplier. I don't need to know, how does this method get completion time. Your solution also breaks my class  incapsulation :(

Answer (score 0):

Question: How to test return value correctly?
**Fix:** EXPECTED_TIME = EXPECTED_TIME + (CURTIME_IN_NANOSEC - EXPECTED_TIME), time digit till nano seconds(offset time till current nano second add to EXPECTED_TIME)
ACTUAL_TIME =   subject.performOperationAndGetTimeNano()--This gives time digit till nano seconds

private static final long EXPECTED_TIME = getExpectedLongTime();

long getExpectedLongTime(){} method in mocked java class and used in above class gives EXPECTED_TIME as above. Note in Mockito, Every input data is mocked by Mock java class which has sample Input Data.

B.  Is there way without PowerMock? **Fix:** Yes there is, Simple JUnit like above. No need for mocked java class, we can write seperate method and use like above as in A.

Hope I Answered both your questions.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a code snippet, please? I don't quite understand your solution :(